# replace whole line using sed with variable

Tags: unix, sed

file content

```
something
OIDCRedirectURI http://abc-mt.tc.ac.com/newredirect
something
```

sed command tried

```
URL='xyz-new.com' #This will be forming at run time

sed -i 'abc /c\ OIDCRedirectURI $URL/newredirect' /etc/httpd/conf.d/proxy.conf
```

Basically I want to replace the given URL with the new URL.

But is it replacing with $URL.

Any pointers?

Comment: Use double instead of single quotes. Also, the "assignment" `$URL = '...'` is actually a command. Write `url='...'` instead. I recommend https://www.shellcheck.net.

Comment: Your sed substitution syntax is not correct. Pls show a line as an example from your file, before and after.

Comment: @Kent I update the question so you have more clarity now.

Comment: @Socowi Double quotes not working in my case. I update the question so you have more clarity.

Comment: In the updated question you are still using single quotes `'` instead of double quotes `"`. Apart from that, your main problem is the `sed` command as pointed out by Kent. Fixing the quotes is only the first step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the new URL is saved in a shell variable: `$URL`
This one-liner may help you:

```
sed -i "s@\(^OIDCRedirectURI \).*@\1$URL/newredirect@" file
```

In your example, the `URL` is not with a protocol, e.g. HTTP or https. If you want to "reuse" the protocol prefix from the "old" URL, you can add it to the capture group:

```
sed -i "s@\(^OIDCRedirectURI http[^/]*//\).*@\1$URL/newredirect@" file
```

### just to show it is working:

```
kent$  cat /tmp/test/f
something
OIDCRedirectURI http://abc-mt.tc.ac.com/newredirect
something

kent$  URL='this.is.new.url'

kent$  sed -i "s@\(^OIDCRedirectURI http[^/]*//\).*@\1$URL/newredirect@" /tmp/test/f

kent$  cat /tmp/test/f
something
OIDCRedirectURI http://this.is.new.url/newredirect
something
```

Comment: It's giving me an error: No such file or directory. conf.d/proxy.conf, This is because I need to pass the full path of file - /etc/httpd/conf.d/proxy.conf. and the file path / is getting mixed with sed command /.

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal No it won't. the separator of `s` in sed is `@`, the `/` is not a problem. It must be something else.

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal check the test in answer

Comment: Thanks a lot! Finally, it seems working. There was definitely some issue at my end.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use sed for this, personally.

```
#!/bin/sh -x

mystring="OIDCRedirectURI http://abc-mt.tc.ac.com/newredirect"
redir=$(echo -e "${mystring}" | cut -d' ' -f1)
oldurl=$(echo -e "${mystring}" | cut -d' ' -f2)
newurl="http://xyz-new.com"

echo -e "${redir} ${newurl}"
```

Granted, you probably want to do this in a loop with a list of such entries, but that wouldn't be too difficult.  You'd just have to put your old URLs and new URLs in two stack files, and make sure that they were in the correct sequence within each.